# Why does Ubuntu Linux swap buttons like ok/cancel on dialogs and keep/discard in Chrome?

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, user-interface

With all the differences between Linux and Windows, this one boggles me the most. Why not agree on a standard? Do they remain different just to be different? Generally this isn't a big problem until you make the mistake of clicking one if you're used to the other.

Comment: Standardization kills innovation.

Comment: The best part about standards is that there are so many to choose among.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu is agreeing on a standard, it is just not the standard which was set by Windows. Ubuntu is following the [GNOME Human Interface Guideline](http://developer.gnome.org/hig-book/stable/index.html.en). You can find the part about the placement of the OK and Cancel buttons in [section 3.4.2](https://web.archive.org/web/20130922172031/https://developer.gnome.org/hig-book/stable/windows-alert.html.en) (link to archived version in internet archive).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu tries to standardise things a bit, which means some buttons get moved around. They coudl standardise with the other button arrangement, but that would mean moving other things around and upset someone else.

They also move the "preferences" menu items in a lot of programs, Firefox for instance, so that it is in more-or-less the same place in more apps.

Comment: Your post seemed to say Ubuntu follows a standard while other OSes don't, which is not true. Every platform has a standard to follow, whether it's Android, Windows, macOS or any other operating systems

Comment: No, that Ubuntu tries to enforce a more standard look by tweaking application themes/skins where they differ from the standard. Ubunto and Windows both have UI standards, just not the same ones, and applications often ignore them in either case.

Comment: The difference in Ubuntu's buttons are not because it's modifying apps' interfaces. It's because the [human interface guidelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_guidelines) in Linux and Mac already have different button positions compared to Windows

Answer (score 0):

The Keep and Discard buttons in Chromium have a purpose. Besides, the standard is OK and Cancel. You'll see these buttons on other Chromium dialogues. Oh, you usually access preferences in Edit > Preferences as opposed to Tools > Options in Windows.